# I have trouble to understand the meaning of "もこれで" in a sentence

Tags: meaning

I'm having trouble to understand もこれで in a sentence.

This is the sentence with もこれで:

たったひとり、命がけのしゅぎょうもこれで最後だ.

I will translate this by:

"this is the conclusion of a solitary life-or-death training." I don't understand which meaning to give to "もこれで". I don't know which additional information it brings.

Could someone help me ?

thank you

Comment: Try like this: `「命がけのしゅぎょうも、これで最後だ」`

Comment: I had the feeling that これで was linked to 最後だ but I didn't how. Thx.

Answer (score 4):

The も is for emphasis.  It does NOT mean "also".  In this context, the も implies that the speaker feels that the training has been hard and/or long and it is finally ending.

これで simply means "with this".  It is referring to the last part of the training.

Comment: ok I see now. I didn't know that も could also means an emphasis. For これで i didn't know how to translate it more than "with this" which wouldn't sound right in a translation. so I understand now it's just to link the two parts of the sentence.  Thank you very much for you enlightening.